# Which of these wireless adapters work in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, compatibility, adapter

Well, I just upgraded one of my machines to windows 7, and it turns out that my usb wireless adapter just isn't working. There is no driver for it in windows 7 (yes, I've looked everywhere). So I'm willing to buy a new one, but want to make sure it's gonna work perfect. So it either needs to have a windows 7 driver or have a vista driver that works under windows 7.

I checked my local hardware store, and there are no adapters there with drivers for windows 7, but there are some that have drivers for vista. I don't mind using a vista driver, as long as it works OK. I'd hate to have a buggy internet connection. These are the ones I found that have vista drivers:

Encore Eletronics: [ENUWI-G](http://www.encore-usa.com/product_item.php?region=us&bid=2&pgid=4&pid=18)
Encore Eletronics: [ENUWI-N](http://www.encore-usa.com/product_item.php?region=us&bid=2&pgid=2&pid=277)
Linksys: [WUSB300N](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/US/en/support/WUSB300N)
Linksys: [WUSB54GC v1.0](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/US/en/support/WUSB54GC)

So I ask thee: **Has anyone here tested one of these Wifi USB adapters in windows 7 64bit? Did it work? If it did, did you have to do anything special?**

Thanks in advance. I tried asking the actual salespeople at the store, but they don't know.

EDIT: Forgot to say, it's 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have the ENUWI-N USB WLAN adapter and it works fine with Windows 7 x64

Comment: By the way, did it install automatically when you plugged it in? Or did you have to install the vista driver?

Comment: my installation disk is heavily vLited (disk space is scarce on a SSD so i had all drivers removed), i just downloaded the latest driver from their website.

Answer (score 0):

Right in the linksys pages that you linked is this Windows 7 compatibility list for their adapters...

http://linksys.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/linksys.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=20872

Comment: That information says that WUSB54GC v3.0 is compatible, not WUSB54GC v1.0. And indeed, I did find windows 7 drivers for the 3.0 version, but not for the 1.0.

Comment: Of course, it might just turn out that WUSB54GC v1.0 works too, but I'd rather not assume that. :) And that's why I'm here.

Comment: If you really want a reliable device, you need to get something that is certified to work with your OS. If there are bugs and a product isn't certified, you're going going to get an update for it, but if Linksys lists something as certified, then there  will eventually be an update. You're better off waiting and ordering one online that is 7-certified instead of buying one and hoping it works.

Answer (score 0):

At first, the WUSB54GC v1.0 did work with Windows 7 64 bit. But later it went into a code 10. Microsoft do have a list of wireless adapters that will work with Windows 7. Also, they are working on drivers for the WUSB54GC to work on the Windows 7 64 bit.